# How to change $watch value in unit test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have a directive that look like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr, controller) {
            scope.$watch('data', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                        console.log('data Changed!');
                    }
                });
            },true);

            scope.$watch('myCtrl.search', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                        console.log('myCtrl.search Changed!');
                    }
                });
            },true);
        }
    };
});
```

I am able to change the `data` value and triggle the `$watch` in unit test with this:

```
scope.data = "new data";
scope.$digest();
```

But how can I change the `myCtrl.search` value? I tried with `scope.myCtrl.search = "new search"` and it return error `Cannot set property 'search' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myCtrl` gets attached to the scope due to the `ng-controller=MyController as myCtrl` directive execution. Since this is  a unit test you need to mock the myCtrl too.

In the test setup where you do

`scope = $rootScope.$new()`

also add

`scope.myCtrl={};`

to setup a dummy variable (controller)